Position of shiny dateRangeInput calendar widget inside bs4Dash box sidebar
I am building a dashboard in Shiny using the bs4Dash package and noticed some odd behavior when including a dateRangeInput() widget inside of a boxSidebar(). The calendar widget displays above the input text box instead of below it, preventing the user from changing the month or year of the input (unless typed manually inside the input).
I have a set of four infoBox() KPIs inside the first instance of a fluidRow(), and the box() containing a plot that can be filtered using the date range input inside of the second instance of fluidRow(). I suspect this may be part of the problem, as the strange calendar widget behavior does not occur if I remove the first instance of fluidRow() containing my info boxes entirely. Here's the code for a minimally reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2024-12-20", "2024-12-21")),
  value = 1:2
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      lapply(1:4, function(x) {
        infoBox(
          title = paste0("Info Box ", x),
          value = x,
          width = 3,
        )
      })
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        collapsible = FALSE,
        plotOutput("examplePlot", width = "100%"),
        sidebar = boxSidebar(
          id = "exampleSidebar",
          width = 40,
          dateRangeInput(
            inputId = "exampleDateRangeInput",
            label = "Select Date",
            format = "M dd, yyyy",
            width = "100%"
          ),
          easyClose = FALSE
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$examplePlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(date, value)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Which produces the following odd widget behavior:


you can include some custom css and change the z-index of the date-picker to be very high. The z-index basically is the order of layers on a html page.
EDIT: I added some small part to push down the datepicker by 160 px so that the pop-up does not obscure any boxes on top.
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2024-12-20", "2024-12-21")),
  value = 1:2
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    # Include custom CSS
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      /* Ensure the datepicker dropdown appears above other elements */
      .datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu {
        z-index: 1050 !important;
      }
  
      /* Adjust placement of the date range input widget */
      .shiny-date-range-input.form-group.shiny-input-container.shiny-bound-input {
        margin-top: 160px !important; /* Add spacing above the widget */
      }
    "))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      lapply(1:4, function(x) {
        infoBox(
          title = paste0("Info Box ", x),
          value = x,
          width = 3
        )
      })
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        collapsible = FALSE,
        plotOutput("examplePlot", width = "100%"),
        sidebar = boxSidebar(
          id = "exampleSidebar",
          width = 40,
          dateRangeInput(
            inputId = "exampleDateRangeInput",
            label = "Select Date",
            format = "M dd, yyyy",
            width = "100%"
          ),
          easyClose = FALSE
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$examplePlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(date, value)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
As you can see, that works and nothing is obscured:


Thank you! This is a great work-around for now, but it does happen to obscure one of the info boxes. Do you happen to know why the calendar widget renders above the text box input instead of below it as it normally does? I'm guessing that may be JavaScript behavior rather than CSS

@cristian-vargas Glad I could help! I changed it so that it does not obscure the info boxes anymore. Sadly, I don't know why it chooses to be on top rather than below. My best guess is that the web component chooses this based on screen space above or below.
